# Cannot move huge files from sql server to adls gen2 in json.gz using adf

Tags: json, sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to move the files I have in sqldw to ADLS gen2 storage. I want the files in json.gz in the blob storage. I tried compressing it and moving, but the files are still too big and the minimum file size in ADLS gen 2 is 2.1mb, some of my files are around 4gb. How to solve this?[What I see when I open these files in ADLS gen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqXpZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to a 2.1 MB file size maximum (not minimum) in the storage browser viewer/editor in the Azure Portal - not ADLS.  Currently, ADLS supports block blobs that are up to 190.7 TB in size.  You could download the files via the storage browser to view them.

See [Azure Blob Storage Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#:%7E:text=Maximum%20storage%20per%20Azure%20subscription%3A%201%20GB%3A,Maximum%20size%20per%20file%20upload%3A%20100%20MB%20)

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, I just wanted to understand, if there is any way to compress the files to less that 2.1MB? All my compressed files are exceeding the limits.